# good macro practice in c

Tags: c, macros

what is the better way to use macro and why
1)

```
CHECK(foo());
#define CHECK(foo) do{                            \
                           UCHAR status = foo;    \
                           if(0 != status)        \
                              // do some stuff    \
                              return status;      \
                        }while(0)
```

or 
2)

```
UCHAR status = foo();
CHECK(status);

#define CHECK(status) do{                            \
                           if(0 != status)        \
                              // do some stuff    \
                              return status;      \
                        }while(0)
```

#### edited

thank You for all of You guys, a lot of people say that it is not good to use such piece of the code, but I have a lot of such pieces in my code (which I didn't write, only modify), what can You suggest?

Comment: To me, the first form is the more general and also (just imo) the more readable.

Comment: Neither is good as macros IMO shouldn't do flow control.

Comment: @geek 24 questions asked, 0 votes cast. That's pretty poor participation. Have a read of the [faq].

Comment: @David Heffernan: Where does it say in the faq that you *should* be voting? (As a side note, it is a fundamental right in every decent democracy that you are not forced to vote, which is a good thing!)

Comment: @user786653, I would moderate that statement. Macros that do flow control should at least reflect that fact in their name. Something like `ON_ERROR_RETURN` or so.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Because I *can* and *want to*, not because I *must*.

Comment: @bitmask: Since when? Slightly OT but democracy would work a lot better if everyone were forced to vote, and I don't see how it would be stepping on your freedom of opinion as long as you could always just write-in yourself when you don't support any of the major candidates... To bring this back to relevance, SO works best if members are at least encouraged to participate in the system...

Comment: @bitmask FWIW in some successful democracies voting is compulsory. Anyway, I was just encouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the first one, since it takes care of avoiding multiple evaluation of `foo`, and who uses it doesn't need to remember to create the extra variable.

Still, personally I don't like macros that alter the execution flow like that, a programmer first seeing the codebase can easily miss a return point of the function.

Comment: but if I have a LOT such pieces of the code, what may be better than this?

Comment: I think it's fine for a small DSL for reading a config file or running a state machine where code conciseness has higher importance and you can have the presupposition that whoever touches the code understands what those macros do.

Comment: Sure, I'm not saying that they must be avoided at all cost, I'm just saying that, as always, you have to consider the clarity/convenience tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is easier to use since there is no need for the caller to worry about multiple evaluations of `foo()`. Option 1 also keeps the scope of the `status` variable as small as possible. Option 2 leaks the status variable into the scope of the caller.

Option 3 which doesn't use a macro at all is even better!